# roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo mistake

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote this command in terminal:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch
```

But, this error has occurred in terminal:

```
[turtlebot3_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot3_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287171/roslaunch-turtlebot3_gazebo-mistake/) by [kuzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/34417/kuzey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-31**:
@kuzey Welcome! I removed the part of your question mentioning that you need urgent help. Although understandable, it's considered [bad form](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Etiquette) to mention deadlines as everyone here has them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a question that comes up quite often. Please do a thorough search before asking next time, or at least let us know that you've tried solutions in answers that you found and the results. You should try searching the error on Google using the following format:

```
<error> site:answers.ros.org
```

or for [this problem specifically](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bturtlebot3_world.launch%5D+is+neither+a+launch+file+in+package+%5Bturtlebot3_gazebo%5D+nor+is+%5Bturtlebot3_gazebo%5D+a+launch+file+name+site%3Aanswers.ros.org)

```
[turtlebot3_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot3_gazebo] a launch file name site:answers.ros.org
```

Please see the highly upvoted answer for this question #q143496

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0